# Graph pruning whilst ensuring connectivity

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

Problem: I have a graph (in this instance, it's represented by a matrix which is $\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$). In the raw graph, all nodes are connected to every other node (except themselves) in some way.

I am wanting to prune the graph using the edge weights (say keep the $m$ largest connections to each vertex and prune everything else), however I need to ensure the following conditions are satisfied:

- For each vertex, there must exist a path to any other vertex (directly or indirectly).
- This must be done in such a way to ensure that the graph remains as sparse as possible, keeping the number of connections to a minimum (i.e. only $m$ connections preferred, but more may be required to ensure indirect connectivity).

Is there a reasonably efficient method for doing this? I realize that the computational cost will be a function $n$, and likely NP hard, but I'd like to keep the cost as low as possible. In some of my applications, $n$ may be a few hundred.

Comment: So to be clear, the reason you don't want a minimum spanning tree is because then some vertices would have less than $m$ adjacent edges?

Comment: Yes. Having a lower bound on the number of connections is important. It would be ok to have more on a local scale if this is required to guarantee connectivity, but these extra connections should be kept to a minimum.

Comment: You could try adapting the [reverse-delete algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse-delete_algorithm) to your problem by not deleting an edge if it disconnects the graph or reduces any vertex's degree below $m$. But I don't know if it remains optimal under this modification.

Comment: I don't think optimal is particularly important for my application, provided the structure holds.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're looking for a [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree). There are all sorts of popular algorithms for obtaining a minimum spanning tree; for example, [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm) can do this in $O(|E| \log |V|)$ by using an appropriate data structure.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, there's also Prim's algorithm for doing the same.

Comment: Hmm, it seems I haven't communicated my requirements clearly enough. I must keep `m` connections (at least) to each vertex whilst ensuring the connectivity constraints are met. Obviously, it may not be possible to ensure connectivity between all nodes using only `m` connections, and so in some cases it may require `m+1`, `m+2` etc. I will update my question for clarity.